# Flutter for web: back/forward button problem

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I am facing the following problem:

I have a StatefulWidget which can generate different view in case of state change:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _changed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return changed ? View2() : View1();
  }
}
```

If I change a state `_changed` to `true` and hit the back button, a then the forward button, I would like my application to create fresh `_HomePageState` and display a `View1`, but currently the `View2` is presented, so I believe that the state is persisted somehow.

How can I force rebuild of the widget's state?

Example app presenting the problem: [link](https://flutlab.io/sandbox/d1d83ab2-67fd-4e13-81d8-22c5cd9ea77f)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open some site, eg. [www.google.com](https://www.google.com)
2. Paste the link to the app [https://issueapp.tiiny.site](https://issueapp.tiiny.site/)
3. Change the state of the app by pressing a button
4. Press browser's back button
5. Press browser's forward button

GIF presenting the issue:

[image]

Full code which reproduces the problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const Application());

class Application extends StatelessWidget {
  const Application({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const HomePage();
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _changed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Text(_changed ? "CHANGED" : "NOT CHANGED"),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () { setState(() { _changed = !_changed; }); },
            child: const Text("CHANGE"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `UniqueKey`: `MyHomePage(key: UniqueKey())`

Comment: It is not happening with me. I am getting it `NOT CHANGED` only after performing the bug reproduction steps that you added

Comment: @MendelG Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: @mandy8055 As you can see in the attached GIF - it happens to me, on various browsers.

Comment: It might be related to Back/Forwad cache (browsers' feature), but I am not sure how it is handled with Dart/Flutter.

Comment: Could someone elaborate on @JerryM 's comment?

Comment: Can you provide information about how `Application ` is called?

Comment: Have you modified your `web/index.html` file? If yes, can you provide your modifications?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do that, the easiest way now is just adding a wrapper as a parent widget, that receives a callback when you press the back button from your browser, and then restart the widget.

Results:

[image]

Code:

- You need to call `MyParentWidget` first.
- You can use any widget to refresh the key, I'm just using setState for simplicity.

```dart
class MyParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyParentWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyParentWidget> createState() => _MyParentWidgetState();
}

class _MyParentWidgetState extends State<MyParentWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyHomePage(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      onBackPressed: () {
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    required this.onBackPressed,
    super.key,
  });

  final VoidCallback onBackPressed;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _changed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => Future(() {
        widget.onBackPressed();
        return false;
      }),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Text(
            _textForCurrentState(),
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _changed = !_changed;
              });
            },
            child: const Text("CHANGE"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  String _textForCurrentState() {
    return _changed ? "CHANGED" : "NOT CHANGED";
  }
}
```

Comment: note: this only prevents that you go back to the previous page and refresh the state of your web, otherwise you couldn't restore the state if you press the forward button because the page is re-created from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not solve my problem. What you've shown is probably working because of navigation history enabled. It can be turned of with `url_strategy` package. I used it with your code sample, check: https://pastebin.com/wX4NvkyV

Answer (score 1):

This only happen on release version of flutter web. Your flutter web state will be keep in navigation stack, until you do a page refresh.

Here some additional comment from flutter web issue related to **Refreshing browser resets navigation stack and local variables** :

> When you refresh the page, the entire app is destroyed and launched again. This is how the browser works, nothing specific to Flutter here. So the values of local variables are expected to disappear.
>
> The way navigation works today is by keeping the navigation stack in memory. This means the stack is destroyed on page refresh, and the history is lost.

[Read the github complete comment here by mdebbar](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59277#issuecomment-647761027)

Comment: Ok, so let's say the navigation stack is guilty. I guess it is created by MaterialApp itself. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Moreover, it is also happening in debug version of flutter web. You can see it on the GIF attached to my original post.

Comment: I don't know why I can't reproduce this behaviour in debug mode using `flutter run -d chrome/edge`. Hope will post update after found some practical solutions.

Comment: You can try using this sample I posted under some answer below: pastebin.com/wX4NvkyV

Comment: I decided to host the example page: https://issueapp.tiiny.site/

Comment: I tried you tinyUrl link.
I don't have the problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your screen is not changing, So browsers are not detecting. You can use `WillPopScope` see below code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const Application());

class Application extends StatelessWidget {
  const Application({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const HomePage();
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _changed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        setState(() {
          _changed = !_changed;
        });
        return false;
      },
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text(_changed ? "CHANGED" : "NOT CHANGED"),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () { setState(() { _changed = !_changed; }); },
              child: const Text("CHANGE"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your Column with `WillPopScope` & add the below condition for its `willPopScope` property,

```
onWillPop: () async {
        setState(() {
          _changed;
        });
        return true;
      },
```

However, I'll recommend using state management tools like value notifiers or change notifiers to have a smooth process.